# Building Boost with Process by Conan

Tags: c++, boost, conan, boost-interprocess, boost-process

I'm using Conan to manage my dependencies; my project requires Process and Interprocess components. How can I add these components to my Boost build with Conan? I'm using Boost 1.75 and Conan 1.44 on Windows 10

Comment: Is conan already bootstrapped in your CMakeLists.txt? If so, you should just be able to add `boost::process` and `boost::interprocess` to `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: @parktomatomi Thanks for the quick response; but cmake reports it is unable to find process in Boost if I use boost::process

Comment: Can you include your CMakeLists.txt and the error message in your question?